# Dynamically generating models and validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently performing a webapi call, then essentially mapping the JSON to a pre-defined model (which defines validation attributes, etc) for my view.

However, the JSON I am getting, includes metadata for each field (such as type, required?, validation regex), so I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically generate my models with the appropriate validation rules.

What I'm thinking is, it would be nice to present a form based on the webapi data, which could also be used for POSTing back to it, without all the conversion to pre-defined models with pre-defined attributes.

Any ideas here?  Maybe I'm missing something obvious as this is my first dealing with REST and mapping to objects, I'm using JSON.Deserialize to populate.

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
  "Fields": [
    {
  "Alias": "Title",
  "Name": "salutation",
  "DataType": 4,
  "DataTypeString": "OptionSet",
  "Mandatory": true,
  "Editable": true,
  "Order": 1,
  "CurrentValue": 0,
  "Options": [
    {
      "Name": "Mr",
      "Value": "0",
      "Default": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "Mrs",
      "Value": "1",
      "Default": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ms",
      "Value": "2",
      "Default": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "Miss",
      "Value": "3",
      "Default": false
    }
  ],
  "OptionLinks": []
},
{
  "Alias": "First Name",
  "Name": "firstname",
  "DataType": 1,
  "DataTypeString": "String",
  "Mandatory": true,
  "ValidationRegex": [
    "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
  ],
  "Editable": true,
  "Order": 2,
  "Options": [],
  "OptionLinks": []
},
{
  "Alias": "Middle Name",
  "Name": "middlename",
  "DataType": 1,
  "DataTypeString": "String",
  "Mandatory": true,
  "ValidationRegex": [
    "^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$"
  ],
  "Editable": true,
  "Order": 3,
  "Options": [],
  "OptionLinks": []
},
{
  "Alias": "Surname",
  "Name": "lastname",
  "DataType": 1,
  "DataTypeString": "String",
  "Mandatory": true,
  "ValidationRegex": [
    "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
  ],
  "Editable": true,
  "Order": 4,
  "Options": [],
  "OptionLinks": []
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the sample Json that you receive to see?

Comment: I think you might be looking for dynamic objects. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic But handle with care as using dynamics is quite fragile.

Comment: Added example JSON I'm getting back.  I'm using NewtonSoft for the JSON manipulation.  My thinking is having a collection of field objects that hopefully NewtonSoft can populate directly via deserialize, and then I can either dynamically create models based on requesting specific fields, or I will need to map said fields to my pre-defined Models.  In any case there is still question around dynamic use of metadata...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a proper model, with a collection of Field objects, and then the views dynamically pull the relevant Field objects for a given page.  Then we created a custom model binder to check validation, etc etc.